# Seaborn histplot with one element gives "`bins` must be positive" error

Tags: python, matplotlib, debugging, seaborn

When I run the following

```
sns.histplot([0.49928], binwidth=0.03)
```

I get

```
ValueError: `bins` must be positive, when an integer
```

I believe this happens because seaborn thinks the number of bins for the histogram is < 1. Interestingly it happens when for certain input values (like 0.49928) and not for others (like 0.49927). I don't yet see a pattern regarding what inputs it throws an error for and what numbers it doesn't. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is your goal to find out why this strange input provokes this strange and inconsistent error message? Or do you really want this as a histogram and are these data just an edge case?

Comment: To figure out why this strange input causes his strange and inconsistent error message. I came across it when trying to debug something else. Doesn't impact what I'm doing if this code runs or not, but I'm curious if anyone knows why it's happening.

Comment: I think it is an error in file `_statistics.py` in file `_define_bin_edges` [line 263](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/9425588d3498755abd93960df4ab05ec1a8de3ef/seaborn/_statistics.py#L263) : in case `start` and `stop` are equal,  `np.arange(start, stop+step, step)` sometimes has length 1 sometimes 2 depending on floating point approximation.  A related problem will happen when `stop` is at an integer multiple number of `step`s from `start`, and sometimes a superfluous edge will be added.  I suppose @mwaskom prefers this kind of logic being handled inside `np.histogram_bin_edges`.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a bug in Seaborn to me (although a pretty minor one, not easy to trigger in a normal case). It is passing `bins=0` to numpy's hist function. Looks like something with float precision

Comment: Thanks all! I opened a github issue here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2721